# How to debug webkit crash log in iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, webkit, wkwebview

We got crash log like this(**Only crash on iOS 9**):

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0x00000000815fe0fd

And detail

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  WebKit                         0x281aa862 std::__1::__function::__func<WebKit::WebsiteDataStore::fetchData(WebKit::WebsiteDataTypes, std::__1::function<void (WTF::Vector<WebKit::WebsiteDataRecord, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>)>)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<WebKit::WebsiteDataStore::fetchData(WebKit::WebsiteDataTypes, std::__1::function<void (WTF::Vector<WebKit::WebsiteDataRecord, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>)>)::$_0>, void (WebKit::WebsiteData)>::destroy_deallocate() + 29
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20a37e09 object_dispose + 20
2  WebKit                         0x2808fbaf std::__1::__function::__func<WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::fetchWebsiteData(WebCore::SessionID, WebKit::WebsiteDataTypes, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)>)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::fetchWebsiteData(WebCore::SessionID, WebKit::WebsiteDataTypes, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)>)::$_0>, void (WebKit::WebsiteData)>::destroy_deallocate() + 30
3  WebKit                         0x280518d5 WTF::HashTable<unsigned long long, WTF::KeyValuePair<unsigned long long, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)> >, WTF::KeyValuePairKeyExtractor<WTF::KeyValuePair<unsigned long long, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)> > >, WTF::IntHash<unsigned long long>, WTF::HashMap<unsigned long long, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)>, WTF::IntHash<unsigned long long>, WTF::HashTraits<unsigned long long>, WTF::HashTraits<std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)> > >::KeyValuePairTraits, WTF::HashTraits<unsigned long long> >::deallocateTable(WTF::KeyValuePair<unsigned long long, std::__1::function<void (WebKit::WebsiteData)> >*, unsigned int) + 48
4  WebKit                         0x2808f449 WebKit::NetworkProcessProxy::networkProcessCrashedOrFailedToLaunch() + 252
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x246f7a4f WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 310
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x246f7ebb WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 22
7  CoreFoundation                 0x21255dff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
8  CoreFoundation                 0x212559ed __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 452
9  CoreFoundation                 0x21253d5b __CFRunLoopRun + 794
10 CoreFoundation                 0x211a3229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
11 CoreFoundation                 0x211a3015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
12 GraphicsServices               0x22793ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
13 UIKit                          0x25877189 UIApplicationMain + 144
14 Our App                         0x7187e5 main (main.m:20)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x20e4b873 (Missing)
```

We use `WKWebView` to show some web page. And using `WKUserContentController` as bridge to do some call between H5 and Native.

**So, how to debug this kind of crash?**

I tried to read the source code of [Webkit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit), but it is useless. I only figure out that the WebKit network process is about to exit when crash happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried to reload webview when WKKit process crashed, and the crash is gone。

```
- (void)webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:(WKWebView *)webView {
    [_webView reload];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur researchs. Hope this will help to us too.